# How to compare byte-packed string in Java?

Tags: java, string-comparison

My Java application has a byte-packed String object that is assembled from remote data received that over an external connection.  The string is assembled, like so:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[20];
/* ... buffer is loaded ... */
int j = 9;
String strVal = "";
for( i=0; i<8; i++ )
{
    strVal += (char)buffer[j++];
}
strVal += '\0';
```

Later, I need to validate the received data, but when I attempt the following it returns false.  Both the data in the buffer and the contents of `strVal` (at least as what I can view in the debugger) are what I would expect.  Any ideas?

```
return strVal.equals("STR GOOD"); // evaluates as false when should be true
```

Comment: Have you tried to do a simple System.out.println(strVal); Just to see what is stored in strVal. By the way why are you doing this strVal += '\0'; in java? I dont think you need that in java take it out and see if it solves the problem.

Comment: Why do you append a '\0' to the strVal?

Comment: And why do you use j as index in buffer[] in the loop? Shouldn' that be i?

Comment: I think he use the j because he doesnt want the full word he only whants the word store between the possition 9 and 17.

Comment: What do you mean by "byte packed"? Your code seems to imply that the bytes are simply the ASCII bytes, which is not really "packed", just encoded with a single-byte character set, so use [**`new String(buffer, 9, 8, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII)`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String-byte:A-int-int-java.nio.charset.Charset-) to convert 8 bytes starting at index 9 to a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the `'\0'` from the end of the byte array resolved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Don't append 0, use i in the loop:

```
    byte[] buffer = new byte[20];
    /* ... buffer is loaded ... */

    String strVal = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        strVal += (char) buffer[i];
    }
```

Comment: You can also look at this answer that explain very well why you dont need \0 in the string. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26558741/what-does-strnewlength-0-mean

Comment: Why are you assuming that when OP specifically wrote code to extract string starting at index 9, OP didn't mean it? Your answer reads like "use i in the loop" is the solution to "Don't append 0", and that is certainly not the case. To not append 0, simply remove that statement that is *after* the loop, which is the statement that explicitly adds a 0.